# how can i inclue a wiki page with attachments list in another wiki page in redmine?

Tags: wiki, redmine, redmine-plugins

redmine offer some codes like '{{include(Foo)}}' to include a wiki page. but it dosen't inclue the attachments list froms the Foo page.

i want to include a wiki page with the attachment like below. is there a plugin that can make this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no plugin that lets you include attachments since they are essentially not part of the wiki page. However you can include images in the wiki page you include, they then are shown in the wiki page that includes the wiki page with the attachments. Maybe you can add a link to an attachment to create a workaround?